# Windows 7 Startup fails after installation

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have installed Windows 7 Ultimate a week ago. Yesterday I've noticed that the SP1 update is available. After installation of SP1 the computer failed to start, and had shown a **black screen**. I couldn't even go to safe mode and **F8 didn't help**.

After some fixing attempts including *system restore, startup repair, bootmgr & BCD rebuilding from CMD*, I have decided to reinstall Windows (after all, it's only a week old)

**After the successful installation,** I have decided to first install *all* available updates before I continue. So after the updates download & installation, the computer rebooted. And now I didn't see the black screen again - but in the "Starting Windows..." screen the logo didn't appear and the system didn't startup. Here I could go to safe mode selection window, but it didn't work either ("Loading Windows Files" but nothing).

I've also tried:

- I thought that the CD was corrupted, so **I've used a fresh new disk of Windows**, tried x86 & x64 versions, the same symptoms, no change.
- **Reset the BIOS to default**, no change.
- Memory diagnostic
- HDD diagnostic
- Restarted Windows WITHOUT INSTALLING UPDATES, but it had the same symptom, so maybe Windows Update is not the case?!

I've tried installing it so many times - that I am simply stuck - I can't "reinstall Windows, because it is corrupted...". Maybe the HDD is corrupted? I've also checked it and didn't find a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using Windows 7 SP1 media (instead of updating to SP1 after installing Windows 7)? If you don't have access to it, maybe slipstreaming using a tutorial like [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso/) or [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/145343-slipstream-windows-7-sp1-into-installation-dvd-iso-file.html) will help.

Tip: Use a USB stick for installing. Much faster than a DVD and is easy to modify (say if you want to slipstream other updates as well).

Comment: Yeah, I've also tried using an SP1-integrated media, no change, when I install other updates it still fails to start... But thanks about the idea for using USB! That's new for me

Comment: @Nadav: Yes, you can use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool), and it should work for Windows 8 as well.